# Can we have multiple juju config files?

Tags: juju, maas

as per documentation i have created 1st config file `enviroments.yaml` by `juju generate-config -w` command.

Do I need to create separate" .yaml" file for ceph or openstack services? or i can just add new environment to existing config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to add new files, you can just add new environments in the same file. The example generates a section for openstack already, you can just edit it and uncomment the sections that make sense for your cloud.

Comment: I am installing ceph, so can you show me e.g. enviorments.yaml along with maas environment? I am not getting how to do it?

Comment: Or is it like i have to create seprate .yaml file for installing ceph on MAAS machines? I am so confused, Plz give me a sample .yaml file to install ceph in maas enviornment

Comment: Can you ask that as a new question please?

Comment: I got it working, only thing juju maas is lacking on not good documentation. Its so annoying,  no where specified you have to create separate .ymal file for installing services on maas enviornment!

Comment: My contact information is in my profile, can you send me along what you did to fix it? I can certainly add it to the documentation!

Comment: Hi its just that its nowhere specified to create new .yaml file for the services to be installed in maas or any other environment.
I am new to maas and juju, so for newbie might its sometimes difficult to guess it. :)

Comment: When you do a "juju generate-config -w" it will generate the yaml file for you, you don't need to be doing it by hand! There should be a section in there for MAAS. See https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Also if you could update your question with the version of juju you have that would help.

Comment: Yes, "juju generate-config -w" creates "environments.yaml", there you can specify environments MAAS, hpcloud, ec2,azure etc. where your services will be deployed i.e. either VM or bare metal.

but, for service deployment configuration i created new ".yaml". e.g In my case i installed ceph on nodes available in maas. So i created new .yaml file like given here, in http://ceph.com/dev-notes/deploying-ceph-with-juju/ in section "Prep for Ceph Deployment". I had to create new ceph.yaml file and then "juju deploy -n 3 --config ceph.yaml ceph", which helped, correct me if i am understanding wrong

Comment: i had tried to add ceph.yaml config environment in  default 'environments.yaml" file , which didn't helped so created new ceph.yaml and tried which helped